# How to add more tabs on class product-collateral of product view page

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, tabs

On the view.phtml 175 line i have:

```
    <div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">
      <?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
```

How do I add my custom tabs and contents to "$detailedInfoGroup"?

Comment: Try `http://www.atwix.com/magento/adding-tabs-on-the-product-page/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to add new tab in product detail page then you need to add this code in catalog.xml.

```
  <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description1" as="description2" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
      <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
      <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
      <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Details1</value></action>
  </block>
```

Don't forget to copy this XML file from enterprise package to your selected theme.

Thanks